# select multiple value from single entry through filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table contains the following information

(EmployeeID, DriverLicenseExpiryDate, AutoInsuranceExpiryDate, TWICCardExpiryDate)

How do I select employees with any license expire within certain day(let's say 30 days)?

I am trying to obtain a result like this

```
EmployeeID  ExpiryDate  LicenseType

10001       2017-04-31  Driver license
10002       2017-04-21  Driver license
10002       2017-05-11  Auto insurance
10003       2017-04-20  Driver license
10003       2017-05-01  TWIC card
```

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: something like `select * from table where expirydate <= now() + 30` just replace with proper syntax for your DBMS

Comment: Doesn't this only select employee 1 time?

Comment: it selects all employees who expire date less then now + 30 days

Comment: @Lashane I don't think this is what I am looking for. This query only selects employee with any expiry type I set, but what I am looking for is possible multiple entries of the same employee.

Comment: Then it is up to you to provide desired output, right now I don't understand what you want

Comment: I have posted the desired output in my post above originally. I just can't put my head together on how the select statement you suggested can turn into something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL you'll have the BETWEEN operator which is perfect for this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, DriverLicenseExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'Driver License' AS LicenseType
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE DriverLicenseExpiryDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 30
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, AutoInsuranceExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'Auto Insurance' AS LicenseType 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE AutoInsuranceExpiryDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 30
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, TWICCardExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'TWIC Card' AS LicenseType 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE TWICCardExpiryDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 30
```

If you have the luxury of working in an environment which allows for scripts you can simplify this using variables:

```
DECLARE @startDate AS DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @endDate AS DATE = GETDATE() + 10;

SELECT EmployeeID, DriverLicenseExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'Driver License' AS LicenseType
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE DriverLicenseExpiryDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, AutoInsuranceExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'Auto Insurance' AS LicenseType 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE AutoInsuranceExpiryDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, TWICCardExpiryDate AS ExpiryDate, 'TWIC Card' AS LicenseType 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE TWICCardExpiryDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;
```

Comment: This does select all employee with the proper filter, but I am trying to have multiple rows for employees with multiple license expiring like my post shows.

Comment: uh!  I was thinking of multiple union select but thought there might be another solution. Thanks for providing the detailed solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot the data using `outer apply` and then apply the conditioon:

```
select t.EmployeeId, v.LicenceType, v.ExpiryDate
from t cross apply
     (values ('Driver License', DriverLicenseExpiryDate), 
             ('Auto Insurance', AutoInsuranceExpiryDate),
             ('TWIC Card', TWICCardExpiryDat)
     ) v(LicenceType, ExpiryDate)
where v.ExpiryDate >= getdate() and
      v.ExpiryDate < dateadd(day, 30, getdate();
```

This is the most efficient way to unpivot the data, because the original table is only read once.  In addition, the conditions on the date are only expressed once.

I would also suggest looking closely at the date arithmetic.  `getdate()` has a time component, so it might not do exactly what you want.